# Cannot assign FormArray

Tags: typescript, angular5

just started with learning of Angular and stacked with a problem. I want to create add/remove textfields for the form, therefore I tried the following code in my component.ts file:

```
import {FormBuilder, FormGroup, FormArray } from '@angular/forms';
```

So, this how import looks like and then

```
  nameForm: FormGroup;
  formBuilder: FormBuilder;
  items: any[] = [];

  createItem(): FormGroup {
    return this.formBuilder.group({
      name: '',
      manufacture_date: ''
    });
  }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.nameForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      Name: ''
      items: this.formBuilder.array([ this.createItem() ])
    });
  }

  addItem(): void {
    this.items = this.nameForm.get('items') as FormArray;
    this.items.push(this.createItem());
  }
```

And here is HTML

```
<div formArrayName="items"
     *ngFor="let item of nameForm.get('items').controls; let i = index;">
  <div [formGroupName]="i">
    <input formControlName="name" placeholder="Item name">
    <input formControlName="price" placeholder="Item manufacture date">
  </div>

  Chosen name: {{ nameForm.controls.items.controls[i].controls.name.value }}
</div>
```

Problem is, that I got mistakes with items. Specifically here

```
addItem():
```

I recieve message, that this is **unused method**, and for

```
this.items = this.nameForm.get('items') as FormArray;
```

I got **Type FormArray is not assignable to type any[]. Property "includes" is missing in type FormArray**

And with HTML form I recieve some **Identifier 'controls' is not defined**

Maybe there is another way to make what I want, but for now cant see how to deal with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should change the items type:
 `items: FormArray ;`

and in  ngOnInit():

```
{
    this.nameForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      Name: ''
      items: this.formBuilder.array([ this.createItem() ])
    });
this.addItem()
  }
```

**update:**
there was errors in code i resolved them and updated:

```
nameForm: FormGroup;
items: FormArray;
constructor(public formBuilder: FormBuilder){}

ngOnInit() {
    this.items = new FormArray([new FormControl('name'), new FormControl('manufacture_date')]);
    this.nameForm = new FormGroup({
        items: this.items
    });

    this.addItem();
    console.log(this.nameForm)
    console.log(this.items.controls);
}

addItem(): void {
    this.items = this.nameForm.get('items') as FormArray;
    this.items.push(new FormControl('name'));
    this.items.push(new FormControl('manufacture_date'));
}
```

html:

```
<div [formGroup]="nameForm">
    <div formArrayName="items">
        <div *ngFor="let item of items.controls; index as i">
            <input [formControlName]="i">
            {{item.value}}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Seemingly works, at least removed the errors in component.ts file, but still the same in html. Probably another source of problem?

Anyway, thank you much!